# C++ 11 Best practices for caching in a std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, caching, pass-by-reference, stdmap

(In c++ 11)

I want to store in a map objects (`Product`) that are somewhat expensive to compute. These objects aren't space cheap so I don't want to create unnecessary copies. The map belongs to a `Container` class that will give access to the objects. I made an example that represents what I have (the code is also found here: [run online](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/BgKtIUg7vZ)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class Product
{
private:
  std::string m_id, m_name;

public:
  Product () : m_id (), m_name () { std::cout << "\tProduct default constructor.\n"; }

  Product (const std::string & id, const std::string & name) : m_id (id), m_name (name)
  {
    std::cout << "\tProduct parameters constructor <" << m_id << ", " << m_name << ">.\n";
  }

  Product (const Product & copy) : m_id (copy.m_id), m_name (copy.m_name)
  {
    std::cout << "\tProduct copy constructor.\n";
  }
};

class Container
{
private:
  std::map<std::string, Product> m_products_cache;

public:
  Container () : m_products_cache () { }
  Container (const Container & copy) : m_products_cache (copy.m_products_cache) { }

  Container (const std::string & filename) : Container ()
  {
    // Simulate reading file and storing its contents in map with this:
    m_products_cache.insert (std::pair<const std::string, Product> ("A-001", Product ("A-001", "Product 1")));
    m_products_cache.insert (std::pair<const std::string, Product> ("A-002", Product ("A-002", "Product 2")));
  }

  const Product &
  CreateNewProduct (const std::string & id, const std::string & name)
  {
    std::map<std::string, Product>::iterator product_it = m_products_cache.find (id);

    if (product_it != m_products_cache.end ())
      return product_it->second; // Returns a const-reference to the Product

    std::pair<std::map<std::string, Product>::iterator, bool> inserted_it;
    inserted_it = m_products_cache.insert (std::pair<const std::string, Product> (id, Product (id, name)));

    return inserted_it.first->second; // Returns a const-reference to the Product
  }

  // Case (i)  :  Returns a const-reference.
  const Product &
  GetProductById (const std::string & id) const
  {
    std::map<std::string, Product>::const_iterator product_it = m_products_cache.find (id);

    if (product_it == m_products_cache.end ())
      throw std::out_of_range ("Error: Product ID'" + id + "' NOT found.\n");

    return product_it->second;
  }

  // Case (ii)  :  Uses an non-const reference parameter to return the Product, if found.
  bool
  GetProductById (const std::string & id, Product & product) const
  {
    std::map<std::string, Product>::const_iterator product_it = m_products_cache.find (id);

    if (product_it == m_products_cache.end ()) return false;

    product = product_it->second;
    return true;
  }

  // Case (iii)  :  Uses a const Product non-const pointer reference to expose the Product, if found.
  bool
  GetProductById (const std::string & id, const Product *& product) const
  {
    std::map<std::string, Product>::const_iterator product_it = m_products_cache.find (id);

    if (product_it == m_products_cache.end ())
      {
        product = nullptr;
        return false;
      }

    product = &product_it->second;
    return true;
  }
};

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  Container container ("ignored_filename");

  const Product & created_product = container.CreateNewProduct ("B-003", "Product 3");
  std::cout << "\n - Created Product located at " << &created_product << "\n\n";

  std::cout << " - Obtain reference to Product in container:\n\n";

  const Product & product_reference = container.GetProductById ("B-003"); // Gets product at expected address.
  std::cout << "\tCase i  : product located at " << &product_reference
            << (&product_reference == &created_product ? " (Same object)" : " (Different object)") << "\n";

  Product product_param;
  container.GetProductById ("B-003", product_param); // Question 1: Gets a copy, but doesn't call copy constructor, WHY?
  std::cout << "\tCase ii : product located at " << &product_param
            << (&product_param == &created_product ? " (Same object)" : " (Different object)") << "\n";

  const Product *product_pointer_param;
  container.GetProductById ("B-003", product_pointer_param); // Gets product at expected address.
  std::cout << "\tCase iii: product located at " << product_pointer_param
            << (product_pointer_param == &created_product ? " (Same object)" : " (Different object)") << "\n";
}
```

That produces the following output:

```
 - Created Product located at 0x6000727b8

 - Obtain reference to Product in container:

    Case i  : product located at 0x6000727b8 (Same object)
    Product default constructor.
    Case ii : product located at 0xffffcb40 (Different object)
    Case iii: product located at 0x6000727b8 (Same object)
```

I have the following questions:

1. **Question 1:** This code doesn't return a reference to `0x6000727b8` and instead creates a copy that is stored at `0xffffcb40`, but `Product`'s copy constructor is not called, why?

   ```
   // Case (ii): Output reference parameter
   Product product_param;
   container.GetProductById ("B-003", product_param);
   ```
2. **Question 2:** I'd like to provide access to the object in the map, to avoid creating copies of the object. I must also indicate, with a boolean or an exception, if the `Product` was found. I'd prefer something like **case (ii)**: `bool GetProductById (const std::string & id, Product & product)`, but this doesn't enforce constness.

   Of the three cases I provided in code, or from another suggestion of yours, which is the best practice to achieve it?
3. **Question 3:** In this case, the `Product`s stored in the map will not change after they are stored. But, if the `Product`s were to be changed after they are stored in the map, do approaches like the ones in question 2 still apply?, is it bad practice to change map value objects directly? (I know keys must be constants).

Comment: 1. Because you're not constructing anything. You're assigning to an existing object, using the assignment operator. A constructor, whether a copy constructor or not, gets called only when a new object gets constructed. The statement in question does not construct anything, but it passes a reference parameter, so it's unclear why exactly you expect something to be constructed there. 2-3: one question per stackoverflow.com question, please.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand that I'm assigning to an existing object. But this somehow creates a copy, because if I change something in ``product_param`` (like ``product_param.ChangeName("another name");``) the object in the map remains unchanged. Is this equivalent (in efficiency) to returning a copy of the object in the map?

Comment: TLDR; Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: That's what assigning means. Assigning means copying one object to another object. It doesn't mean constructing a new object. That object has already been constructed, first. You even proudly documented that joyous occasion: "this calls default constructor". Then, by assigning to this constructed object another object, you copied it. If you then proceed to modify something in the copy, that's all that gets modified, the copy. The object that was assigned from is irrelevant, and won't get modified as well. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't fully understand the way that the assignment operator works. Now I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have 2 objects: `product_param` and the object stored in the map. When you assign to `product_param` through the reference `product` it will use the assignment operator `Product::operator=(const Product&)` (which is provided for you by the compiler because you didn't tell it not to) to assign the contents. You still have 2 objects and they each have their own id and name.
2. **case (i)** is fine for one that throws an exception. **case (iii)** is a little awkward but works. Another option is `const Product* GetProductById(const std::string& id) const`. This can return a pointer to the object if it exists or return `nullptr` if it doesn't. This unfortunately has the same prototype as **case (i)** besides the return value, so you'll need to either have a different function name or somehow come up with some other way to distinguish between how to call them.

   The way the standard usually does this is use `operator[](const Key& key)` for the version that doesn't throw and `at(const Key& key)` for the version that does. It will be slightly awkward for one to return a pointer and the other to return a reference though.
3. That's really up to you. There's nothing preventing you from changing the values of a map but if that's not something you want the user to be able to do then you can always return const references or pointers to const back to the user.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really helped, especially by stating the usual way of the standard.